# Process substitution of commands on separate lines of a string

Tags: bash, shell-script, process-substitution

I have a variable, `COMMANDS`, that contains a list of newline-separated commands (I know for example in this case that there will never be newlines, but they could be separated by `NUL`). For example,

```
echo "foo bar"
tail blah.txt
python3 -c 'print(1 + 10)'
```

I would like to invoke each of these, but using process substitution feed them all as arguments into another program. Continuing with the example, if I wanted to feed into `cat`, then I'd expect the following to be run:

```
cat <(echo "foo bar") <(tail blah.txt) <(python3 -c 'print(1 + 10)')
```

Is there any way to dynamically do this? The best solution I could come up was to construct this command as a string and give it to `bash -c`:

```
bash -c "cat$(echo "$COMMANDS" | while read -r p; do printf ' <(%s)' "$p"; done)"
```

But this feels a little brittle (and I question its ability to robustly handle input edge cases like quotes).

For anyone wanting to experiment, here's a quick command to setup what I used as my example:

```
COMMANDS=$(printf 'echo "foo bar"\ntail blah.txt\npython3 -c "print(1 + 10)"')
echo blah > blah.txt
```

Comment: consider an array of commands, so you don't have to worry about newline parsing

Comment: @JeffSchaller I would, but the commands are the output of running another process so newline/`NUL` parsing must be done at some point.

Comment: `readarray -t commands < <(echo 1; echo 2; echo 3)`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Oh nice! I've never seen `readarray`. Will definitely use that more now! :)